# video conferencing stack for embedded devices

Tags: linux, video, embedded, conference

I am looking for a video conferencing stack that I can run on an embedded device. Cam will be connected through USB, hw video acceleration and ethernet is available. We are running linux & directfb. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) might be an option. It is a C stack, and  it is used for a similar purpose (I think) on embedded hardware, ie [TI's davinci processor.](https://gstreamer.ti.com/gf/project/gstreamer_ti/)

I don't know to which extent it is effectively used or useable on such hardware. However, Gstreamer effectively has all the component needed for video and audio
muxing and streaming.

Since it is a pipelined / modular approch, you can plug into gstreamer at any stage, ie keep the video acquisition / compression as custom code, and only use the RTP side of your app to gstreamer.Or you can write a custom compression plugin, and use "standard" gstreamer apps with your custom hardware accelerated hardware.